# How to programatically set database filename?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6.1

Following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj680699), I've created my `DbConfiguration` class:

```
class ImgSigDbConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public ImgSigDbConfig()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0")); 
    }
}
```

And told my `DbContext` to use it:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(ImgSigDbConfig))] 
class ImgSimContext : DbContext 
{
```

Which seems to connect fine, but I have no idea where it's storing my data, and I don't like that. I would like it to save everything to a file in the App_Data folder. How can I specify that from inside my `ImgSigDbConfig` constructor? (Assume I know nothing about SQL server connections)

---

Did some more digging and came up with this:

```
public ImgSigDbConfig()
{
    var sqlConnBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlConnBuilder.DataSource = ".";
    sqlConnBuilder.InitialCatalog = "ImgSim.ImgSimContext";
    sqlConnBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    sqlConnBuilder.AttachDBFilename = @"App_Data\database.mdf";

    SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0", sqlConnBuilder.ToString()));
}
```

But now it throws:

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string

---

Per haim and gunther's suggestions I removed the superfluous connection settings:

```
class ImgSigDbConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public ImgSigDbConfig()
    {
        var sqlConnBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        sqlConnBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        sqlConnBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0", sqlConnBuilder.ToString()));
        SetManifestTokenResolver(new DefaultManifestTokenResolver());
    }
}
```

And moved them into Program.cs:

```
var conn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    AttachDBFilename = @"App_Data\database.mdf",
    //InitialCatalog = "ImgSim.ImgSimContext",
};

using (var db = new ImgSimContext(conn.ToString()))
```

But even so, I get a `System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException` with InnerException:

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

Even though I set a `SetManifestTokenResolver` -- I guess the default one doesn't work??

Comment: I'm not an EF guru so I may be well off hear on what you've understood - but typically you provide a connectionstring in the web.config or app.config who's name matches that of your context (ImgSimContext). This will be the DB that get's used so you know exactly where the data is going. If that's what you're after I'll flesh out an answer.

Comment: @Ian I'd prefer not to write XML if I can do it directly in C#. I don't understand any of this -- I'm used to MySQL + linux. In that environment, I start the mysql daemon, programatically set a few connection settings, and connect to it. I can see the daemon running in my processes, and I can find the data on disk. I can view my data with SqlYog or PMA. I have no idea what Visual Studio is doing for me. Is it starting up an SQL Express server every time I run my app? Is "localdb" some equivalent of sqlite? Where's the data on disk? How do I view it?

Comment: localDB is some sort of light SQL (not sure exactly what). Have you got Sql Server Management Studio? If so launch a connection to `(localdb)\v11.0` I think and you'll see the database listed

Comment: Why do you initialize the context with an invalid connection-string?

Comment: @haim770: Huh..? Because I don't know what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalDbConnectionFactory constructor v11.0 allows to connect to sqlserver 2012 and by default it tries to find the name of the connection string in app.config as context full name. Say you have not specified the connection string in config and want to create a database named Test ( In a datadirectory specified below) then you need to set the constructor like this:

```
   [DbConfigurationType(typeof(ImgSigDbConfig))]
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can call the context :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"c:\App\DataDirectory");
        MyDbContext myDbContext = new MyDbContext("test"); //this is the name
        myDbContext.Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" });
        myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The configuration will remain same:

```
class ImgSigDbConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public ImgSigDbConfig()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"));
    }
}
```

Watch that I am setting the datadirectory manually as it is not a web app. You need to give permissions to this directory so that a new database can be created and attached.
My app.config is like this:

```
    <configuration>  <configSections>    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />  </configSections>  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Well, that did it. I'm not quite sure why that was so complicated.

Comment: How do I give the folder permissions? Anything other than my project folder / App_Data fails?

Comment: You should be able to select the folder, right click properties and then set the user to have write permission under which the app will be running.

Comment: Under what user is your sql server running? Does it also have permissions to this folder?

Answer (score 1):

So by default Entity Framework will look for a connection string to determine which database it should open, the current one it's using is a a version of SQL Expres (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx)). This is just the default setup making development easy for you.

A typical website will have a `web.config` file that you can find. In there you'd expect to see something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
          <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\testdb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

For a windows forms/console application there will be an `app.config` instead, these serve the same purpose however.

This connection string needs to be modified to use the database you're interested in, at this point I'd recommend [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/). You can make it point at SQL, Oracle or whatever you like pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a database based on a connectionstring you give to your ImgSigContext

example:

```
public class ImgSigContext : DbContext{
   public ImgSigContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
}
```

and create it by using

```
string connString = "..."; //here comes a valid connectionstring
bool created = new ImgSigContext(connString).Database.CreateIfNotExists();
//returns true if database didn't exist and is succesfully created
//works from Entity FrameWork 5 and up
```

or like this

```
// will automatically create if migrations is enabled
using(var context = new ImgSigContext(connString))
{
   // some logic comes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the `baseConnectionString` parameter on `MyLocalDbConnectionFactory` constructor explicitly states that:

> The connection string to use for options to the database other than
>   the '**Initial Catalog**', '**Data Source**', and '**AttachDbFilename**'. The
>   'Initial Catalog' and 'AttachDbFilename' will be prepended to this
>   string based on the database name when CreateConnection is called. The
>   'Data Source' will be set based on the LocalDbVersion argument.

Try this instead:

```
var sqlConnBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlConnBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
sqlConnBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
```

If you're running a Console Application make sure your `DataDirectory` is actually set. Use: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")`.

Comment: Aha. Didn't notice that. It is indeed a console app. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")` returns null. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` says "There are no context policies".

Comment: Try to set it to your `App_Data` or rewrite the original `LocalDbConnectionFactory` to accommodate your needs (source: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/LocalDbConnectionFactory.cs).

Comment: Also, if you'll watch `myDbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` (using your current code) you'll find it invalid.